# Facebook requestwithgraphpath error > facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "Operation could not be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I tried the facebook-ios-sdk and followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). After following all the steps when I executed the applications.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" delegate:self];
```

This doesnt seems to be working as I'm getting:

> Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 UserInfo=0x4b65ac0 "Operation could not be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)"

Answer (score 1):

This is an Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token error....You might have logged from another device (if you have "offline_access" permission.if not access token expiry date exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

The same error came to me. At the same time i am running the app in simulator, i also logged into facebook account in the computer browser. The error may be because of this.

The following did the trick to me. 
Once i logged out of the facebook account in computer browser, this particular error is gone in simulator(app), and able to get the friends list and do the rest.

Comment: also one more trick, logout of facebook app in phone & delete the app in phone and install it again and try.